# Regular Expression to replace last occurences of numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried a regular expression to replace last occurrence of numbers from 1 to infinity but its replacing all instances . kindly correct it and help.

```
"test.test.test.1.test.1.".replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
```

In the above expression i need to replace the string `'.1'`, in which any integer may come in place of `1`.

Comment: What is the expected output in this case . Please share it

Comment: Remove the last sequence of digits? `.replace(/\d+(?!.*\d)/, '');`?

Comment: It works but the expected output is "test.test.test.1.test." i.e to remove '1.'

Comment: Try `.replace(/\d+\.*(?!.*\d)/, '')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log( "test.test.test.1.test.1.".replace(/[\d]+[^\d]*$/g, ''));
```